# StanfordCoreNLP compiler errors using javac

Tags: java, compiler-errors, stanford-nlp

I have just started looking into the Stanford NLP libraries. I downloaded and uncompressed the core file that includes everything, then tried to run the demo file (StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java).

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
```

All of the import lines trigger an "error: package edu.stanford.nlp. does not exist" message.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make the demo work?

Comment: You seem to be missing the package in your class path. Download it from maven central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cedu.stanford.nlp

Comment: If you don't want to use it from the Maven central, you just have to add the .jar to your classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the class path while compiling the core java file by
**javac -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar filename.java**

Comment: do I just copy and paste this into my java file?